# How to create an environment file specific for build system using aws code build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I source my environment specific variables from .env file (I'm using dotenv package). This file is not version controlled.

Using code pipeline stage codebuild how do I create this .env file and its contents ?

I'm thinking, I have to use buildspec to create and add content to the .env file, but have no idea how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to get rid of `dotenv` and use real environment variables.

The problem with `dotenv` is that it simply mocks `process.env` inside your `node` process. It does not really modify environment variables for you. They are not available outside of your `node` process.

I would use [`direnv`](https://direnv.net) instead and replace your `.env` files with `.envrc` for local development.

For CI and production environments, the environment variables are now defined in your CodeBuild project so `.envrc` files are not needed.

Please see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409771/how-do-you-handle-config-files-for-aws-codepipelines/46410745#46410745) for more information from another angle.

---

If you wish to continue using `dotenv`, you have several options:

- Store the `.env` file in S3 and retrieve it during the build process.
- Construct the `.env` file using shell scripts and environment variables defined on the CodeBuild project.

I'm sure there are others but they are all hacky for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how about storing env information in buildspec under env parameter-store ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the linked related answer suggests.

Answer (score 8):

So this is actually a simple script, taking the second option of the first answer you can add the following to your buildspec.yml:

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - printenv > .env
```

the shell script `printenv > .env` is all that is needed to output all of your process env to a file.